# Multiple Domains. Multiple Server. One DNS

Tags: linux, networking, dns, windows-server-2008, domain

I want to host multiple domains of my clients on multiple servers. For example 10 Domains on ServerA, 10 Domains on ServerB etc.

So basicly, I want all my clients to have "ns1.main.com" and "ns2.main.com" as their nameserver. And I would assign them to my different servers as I like. (so for example domain1.com goes to IP1 and domain2.com goes to IP2.)

Is this somehow possible to archieve? Where would I assign those different servers?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, that’s no problem. It’s basic DNS, that’s all. Where does Windows Server 2008 come into play?

Comment: Ok Thanks. Im still thinking which os to use :D

Comment: Try [AWS Route53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/).

Comment: If you are in the web hosting business and not in the DNS hosting business then you `SHOULD NOT` host your clients DNS. You can assist them in creating the appropriate DNS record at their existing DNS host.